# compile NodeJS to binary

Tags: node.js, compilation

i want to compile nodeJS into binary, similar to C/C++.

compile

```
$NodeCompile -ofast Node.js -o executable
```

(fine if i can't do compiler settings)
to run it

```
$./executable
```

Comment: There isn't much context in the question so I am really not sure what is the end goal here. However one of the option would be to use pkg `https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg`

Comment: 1. PKG doesn't work for me, i don't have admin powers.                                           2. I am compiling this to prevent other people from stealing my code

Comment: @justanoob How do you have no controll over your own code? "Compile" the code on your developer machine and deploy the exectuable... You are telling us you dont have admin rights on your own computer?

Answer (score 29):

You probably want to look at [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)

It somehow creates a self-contained binary executable from Javascript, including module dependencies and asset files.

Installation and use is easy:

```
$ npm install -g pkg
$ pkg index.js -o my-program
$ ./my-program
```

My understanding is that this binary contains nodejs bytecode.  It also appears that you can cross-compile.

Note: I've tried [`ncc`](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) and [`nexe`](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) also, but I haven't found them to be as useful. `ncc` just creates a self-contained Javascript file and `nexe` encountered a Python error when I tried to use it.

Comment: Add `--targets node8-linux` (or other versions) if your current node version is not supported by `pkg`.

Answer (score 1):

Solver the same thing using [Bun](https://bun.sh/). I added an entry to script in package.json, like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "compile": "bun build src/main.ts --compile --outfile out"
```

I now run it like `bun run compile` and i can use the out file like `./out`