# How to deploy node js to linux ubuntu without source code?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

In windows you can use nssm to make the source code become .exe and make it a service. In Linux I already tried it using pm2 and nginx but it still need the source code.

Comment: The source to Node or the source to your JavaScript application?

Comment: In general you deploy apps as source on Linux-type systems, it's just how it's done. The idea of a self-contained executable is really unusual, and for most deployments, *exceedingly* annoying to deal with. While it's common on Windows to get a bundled `.exe`, that's not how Linux has worked, conventionally speaking.

Comment: source to javascript application (express).

Comment: Java use jar and can deploy without source code. Can node use the same method?

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954743/11395491